# How do I see if multi-word substring in a string exists in dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm trying to check a string for key words, and if the word exists, get the value from the dictionary. The problem exists when the key word is a multi-word phrase.

So I have a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

d.Add("keyword1", "D2");
d.Add("keyword2", "D3");
d.Add("keyword3", "D4");
d.Add("keyword4", "D4");
d.Add("keyword5", "D5");
d.Add("key word six", "D6");
```

And I have a string, which may look like the following but will be a random sentence:

```
string errormessage = "This is an error regarding Key Word Six";
```

I'm currently using the following to check the errormessage and see if any words appear in the dictionary:

```
string code = null;
string theDcode = null;

foreach (string word in errormessage.Split(' '))
{
    if (d.TryGetValue(word, out theDcode))
    {
        code = theDcode;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can't search for the string "Key Word Six" since I'm reading the string word by word and the foreach loop sees each word separately. This works great for single word key words. How can I handle checking for a multi word key word?

Comment: `"I'm reading the string word by word "` *That's* the problem you need to address.  You need to not read them in word by word if you have multi-word keywords.

Comment: Sounds as if you should use a database instead. Should "six key words" also match?

Comment: @TimSchmelter but that will not solve his problem

Comment: @MiserableVariable: Why? Imho a database is the right tool to store and search things. However, a `Dictionary` that must be enumerated is not the most efficient approach.

Comment: @TimSchmelter perhaps I misunderstood. Can you elaborate what you will store in db and what the search algo will be?

Comment: @MiserableVariable: For example full text search and [`CONTAINS`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx)

Comment: @TimSchmelter "six key words" would not have to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate the items in the dictionary instead and check the string for matches.

```
string errormessage = "This is an error regarding Key Word Six";
var d = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

d.Add("keyword1", "D2");
d.Add("keyword2", "D3");
d.Add("keyword3", "D4");
d.Add("keyword4", "D4");
d.Add("keyword5", "D5");
d.Add("key word six", "D6"); 

string code = null;
foreach (var item in d)
{
    var i = errormessage.IndexOf(item.Key, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    if(i >= 0)
        code = item.Value;
}
```

This would however also give you matches inside of words. `testkeyword1test` for example.

**EDIT**
For possible better performance (untested) you could use a regular expression.

```
string code;
var reg = new Regex(GetPatternString(d.Select (x => x.Key)), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
foreach (var match in reg.Matches(errormessage))
{
    code = d[match.ToString()];
}
```

And helper function

```
private static string GetPatternString(IEnumerable<string> values)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var oldStr in values)
    {
        sb.Append("(");
        sb.Append(Regex.Escape(oldStr));
        sb.Append(")|");
    }
    return sb.ToString(0, sb.Length - 1);
}
```

Comment: Would this not be inefficient for large data sets?

Comment: @Magnus - This worked for me.. thank you! It's ok if the keyword exists in the middle of a string. The string I'm searching is typed in by a user, and it's very possible they'll forget to put a space between words or something. The point of this app is to sift through their babble and look for anything important.

Comment: @MiserableVariable the data comes from an XML file .. the one I'm testing with is under 1MB. It runs plenty fast for me!

Comment: For small datasets it probably works, it is just that there is a full string search for every non-match, though string search is itself not a full scan necessarily

Comment: @MiserableVariable I agree, it would not perform well on large strings since it would have the search the complete string every time. I have presented an alternative solution using regular expressions that would possibly work better.

Comment: @Magnus regexp would probably be slower, definitely as described because of the need to recompile the patterns on every iteration. See my answer for a possibly efficient approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating through just the keys of the Dictionary object.

```
foreach (string word in d.Keys)
{
    //Checks here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a single dimensional dictionary (there must be a better word but I don't know it) will not work. You need a tree:

A `trie` like structure:

```
key = 
 key word = 
   key word 6 = D6
   key word 7 = D8
```

So when you find a match on `key`, you compare the next work and so on.

Now, what would you do if you have entry for both 'key word" and "key word 6"? Its a domain question, whether to stop at first or last match

Answer (score 0):

I guess the algorithm isn't terrible but you'll have to do a loop that checks for something like

"This is an error regarding Key Word Six"

1. This
2. This is
3. This is an
4. This is an error
5. This is an error regarding
6. This is an error regarding Key
7. This is an error regarding Key Word
8. This is an error regarding Key Word Six
9. is
10. is an

I guess you'll have to find all the unique substrings in the incoming search. It could easily be done with a loop. But then if I search with "is an", is that the equivalent of "an is"? Does the order of the words matter? Things start to get complicated in a hurry. Seems like you'd want to defer to something like [Lucene](https://github.com/apache/lucene.net) or some search library out there.